# Laravel whereHas and for each of collection

Tags: php, laravel

I would need something like this:

```
$user_ids = [1,2,3]; // 1 as logged user

$chats = Chat::whereHas('users', function ($q) { $q->where('users.id','=',1); })->get();
$c = null;
foreach ($chats as $chat) {
    if ($chats->users->pluck('id')->diff($user_ids)->count() === 0)  {
        $c = $chat;
        break;
    }
}

return $c;
```

Is there some one-liner or simpler solution in laravel to get chat based on relation collection that equals to array of ids without same order within array?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct, you want the first chat that has exactly these user IDs right? then try this:

```php
$user_ids = [1, 2, 3];

$chat = Chat::has('users', '=', count($user_ids))
    ->where(function ($query) use ($user_ids) {
        foreach ($user_ids as $user_id) {
            $query->whereHas('users', function ($q) use ($user_id) {
                $q->where('id', $user_id);
            });
        }
    })
    ->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$chat = Chat::whereHas('users', fn ($q) => $q->whereIn('users.id', $user_ids), '=', count($user_ids))
    ->whereDoesntHave('users', fn ($q) => $q->whereNotIn('users.id', $user_ids))
    ->first();
```

This works